# R Unite function behaving differently in Shiny vs code

Tags: r, shiny, tidyverse

I have a df with this structure:

```
var1   var2
1;2;3  4;4;4
7;2;1  4;1;4
8;2;3  5;4;4
```

If I run

data <- unite(data, "joined", var1,var2, sep = ";", na.rm = TRUE, remove = TRUE)

It works as expected, yet if I run the same code in a Shiny App I get weird values like

```
joined
4;5
7;8
8;4
```

Somehow the characters are collapsed into a single vale and then joined like this. I've tried using a different separator but I get the same results. Weird thing is that the code works as expected but in Shiny is not.

Comment: Not sure why this issue. Outside of shiny I have the error `\`TRUE\` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a logical vector` when using `na.rm = TRUE`. Without this parameter, `unite()`works as expected in both R and Shiny.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example to reproduce this issue?